# Automatically shut down Windows XP after completed MS Backup

Tags: windows-xp, backup, shutdown, windows-backup

A computer in the office is running daily backups (as scheduled task) with the Windows XP built in backup software. The backups are slowing down the computer too much, so we want the backup to run after office hours, but then we want the computer to automatically shut down after the backup is complete.

How do I make the computer to automatically shutdown after a completed scheduled backup?

Comment: Do you have to use MS Backup or can you use a program that has this feature?  I would just set your computer to automatically restart at a certain time which is some point after the backup is finished.

Comment: The downvote should go to the company that doesn't want any other backup software than the MS standard XP builtin solution - you can't blame me for that decision that unfortunately is out of my hands.

Comment: I didn't issue the downvote.

Comment: Sorry. I just assumed that you did since the downvote and your comment was placed within seconds from each other. My apoligies.

Answer (score 2):

An immediate shutdown can be started using:

```
%windir%\system32\shutdown.exe -s -f -t 00
```

To run this command after completion of the backup, you could use a [command script](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntbackup_command_line_examples.mspx?mfr=true) which starts the backup command first and then executes the shutdown.

Example:

```
ntbackup backup \\iggy-multi\d$ /j "Command Line Backup 4" /f "D:\backup.bkf"
%windir%\system32\shutdown.exe -s -f -t 00
```